# diameter of a huge graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, parallel-processing

I have a huge graph that I would like to process using many machines.

I had like to compute if the graph diameter is higher than 50.

How would I split the data and I would I write a parallel algorithm that can calculate it?
(the return value is boolean)

The graph diameter is the greatest distance between any pair of vertices

Comment: I had like a solution for both cases, In general yes it does...
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way to figure this out would be an all-pairs shortest path algorithm -- the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) is a good place to start.  Another option using Hadoop is located [here](http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/ml2008/CMU-ML-08-117.pdf).

Comment: how would you parallelize the Floyd-Warshall algorithm?

Comment: @MrOhad You could find the source for Floyd-Warshall (parallel) here http://pcl.cs.ucla.edu/projects/maisie/tutorial/programming/samples/apsp.m  explanation is here http://pcl.cs.ucla.edu/projects/maisie/tutorial/programming/

Comment: Actually, he doesn't want a parallel algorithm, he wants a distributed one.  Hence the hadoop link.

Comment: I understood the Floyd-Warshall algorithm, which is an awesome one! :-)
the questions is, how do I split it to many computers? it's a DP algorithm, all it does is filling a Matrix row by row(n times)...
I would live to hear your opinion..

Moreover, this is a nice way to find out all the shortest path from each pair of vertices, I am actually looking for the max() on that list, is it really the best way to do so? Thanks!

Comment: Each row can be computed on a separate computer, if I remember correctly, with some message passing between them.  Sadly, since you are interested in weighted graphs, there isn't really much that can make it faster than the all pairs computation -- at least not that I've seen in the literature.  What you could do is bail after you hit 50, though, which should put an upper limit the time, at least.

Comment: The other answer addresses that.

Comment: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node35.html here are few ways to parallel F-W

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Parallel implementation of graph diameter algorithms](http://ditwww.epfl.ch/SIC/SA/publications/SCR98/scr10-page3.html)

Also: [Parallel Graph Algorithms](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~demmel/cs267_Spr10/Lectures/Madduri_Graphs_2010.ppt)